# Will OpenVBX and Twilio handle multiple calls and if one line is busy, go to the next line, etc

Tags: queue, twilio, phone-call, openvbx

Can anyone tell me if my call flow below will work with OpenVBX & Twilio and if so, how to set this up there? I'm using Twilio with a trial number to test it out, but no luck so far. I have downloaded a plugin "OpenVBX-Plugin-Queue-master" that looks like it may work, but I can't get it to. I'm not a telephony expert. I am a programmer. =)

Here is what I need. I need to be able to receive multiple calls at the same time and move the caller to the next available attendants.

- They need to hear the main greeting, press 1
- Then go to the support group ideally (that is not working for me
  right now either)- let's say attendant #1.
- If attendant #1 is on the phone, put them on hold briefly listening
  to another greeting, then send them to attendant #2
- If attendant #2 is busy...repeat the process until I run out of
  attendants and then they go to VM.

Here is my install version:

- Current Version: 1.2.20
- Schema Version: 79
- Latest Schema Available:   79
- Site Revision: 1026

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Support for OpenVBX is not active at this time.

I'd suggest you take a look at the guide for Queues. 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/guides/queues

Beginning with queuing your caller (an example in Ruby):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'twilio-ruby'

# Handles the POST request from Twilio and generates the TwiML that puts caller in a queue.
post '/caller/?' do
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    # Use <Enqueue> verb to place caller in a <Queue>
    r.Enqueue "Queue Demo"
  end
  response.text
end
```

You can handle more sophisticated workflows like iterating through agents via [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/taskrouter/create-tasks).

And this [Call Screening tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/ruby/rails#5) demonstrates how to handle agent voicemail with production ready code.

Please let me know if this helps at all.